# Betting the same number on the roulette table

Tags: probability

Let's say me and my friend play roulette, numbers go from $0$ to $36$. I play twice, the first time I pick $17$ to win and I got it right so I win! I go to play again and want to pick $17$. I believe I'll get the same chance of winning because these are two independent events, my friend believes picking $17$ would be a bad choice because $17$ already came out and because it is a lower chance of two $17$'s coming out in a row it would be disadvantageous to guess that over any other number. Could I get an explanation to settle this debate with a friend over what is right and why?

Comment: they should indeed be independent events, and so the previous result does not affect the chance of it happening again

Comment: [Is this Gambler's fallacy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524010/is-this-gamblers-fallacy) **YES.**

Comment: One thing is an abstract roullete in which all numbers have equal chance and results are independent. Another is a real roullete with imperfections that might lead to greater chances to some numbers. In either case... the probability for winning with a given number won´t change in the next turn given you got the number. But in a real roullet it might not be 1/36. Some gamblers study the results from roulletes in casinos to spot ones with greater probabilities for certain numbers. But it might take sometime to get credible results. And it appears that it is not an impossible possibility.

Comment: You'll get the same chance the second time and every time. Except if the roulette is flawed and biased towards certain numbers (which does not appear on professionnal roulettes, of course), in which case you'll actually get a _greater_ chance to get a $17$ twice, not a lower. So your friend is wrong in any case. :-)

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, I don't believe you are right in your statement related to professional roulettes... unbiased roulettes and unbiased coins are just abstractions... see https://www.888casino.com/blog/concept-of-biased-wheel

Comment: @bluemaster The link you posted says "Please note that 888’s services are not being offered to players residing in your location." (France).